# Not understanding why thread is changing in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

For a particular thread, I have the following code

```
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        currentWord = words.get(new Random().nextInt(words.size()));
        tvForeignWord.setText(currentWord.getWordForeign());
        tvScore.setText("Your score is " + score);
        for (int i = timer_length; i > 0; i--) {
            tvTimer.setText("You have " + i + " seconds remaining.");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //DEBUG e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I appear to be getting this error message:

```
02-19 22:03:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(17236): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

What is the issue?

When I do this instead :

```
public void run() {

    //while (true) {
        currentWord = words.get(new Random().nextInt(words.size()));
        tvForeignWord.setText(currentWord.getWordForeign());
        tvScore.setText("Your score is " + score);
        //for (int i = timer_length; i > 0; i--) {
            //tvTimer.setText("You have " + i + " seconds remaining.");
            //try {
                //Thread.sleep(1000);
            //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //DEBUG e.printStackTrace();
            //}
        //}
    }
```

I get no error?

Comment: You are clearly running this code in another thread apart from the UI thread.

Comment: If so, how come it works when i=5 but not when i=4 ?

Comment: And how come all the other setText methods work?

Comment: Just because some work, doesn't mean that you're doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't update the UI from a separate thread. Either create a Handler object outside your thread and post runnables to that, or try to use context.runOnUiThread() to do your UI operations back on the main thread.

Comment: Would that keep it concurrent though? [specifically the runOnUiThread()]

Comment: Concurrent in what sense? You should have no trouble with this.

Comment: Ok then, I'll implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only the UI thread is allowed to manipulate UI objects. You'll need to set up messaging between your UI thread and your worker threads in order for your worker threads to produce changes on the screen.

Comment: Also, how would I do this?